# Turn Off Point Labels in MS Chart for .NET

Tags: charts, label, series, mschart, points

VB2010 using MS Chart: I've added one series as a point chart. On occasion there are over 1000 points and the point labels become way too jumbled. I have smart labeling ON:

```
cht.Series("srs").SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = True
```

But nonetheless it still looks bad. So I added a context menu to turn off the labels. The user can then zoom in to a spot and if they wish turn labels back on. I cant seem to figure out a way to do this without looping through ALL data points.

I can totally hide the points and labels by

```
cht.Series("srs").Enabled = False
```

But I want just the labels to be hidden and then redisplayed when the user has opted for it.

Any help appreciated.

Edit:
Since I haven't found a method to turn labels off and on with one command I am currently cycling through each point in the series.

```
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Application.DoEvents()

    'suspend updating UI
    cht.Series.SuspendUpdates()

    'cycle through all points in the series and set the label either to an empty string or whatever is cached in the Tag property.
    'todo: this is not efficient for large datasets but its the only thing we have.
    For Each pt As DataPoint In cht.Series("srs").Points
        If mnuDisplayLabels.Checked Then
            pt.Label = pt.Tag.ToString
        Else
            pt.Label = ""
        End If
    Next pt

    'resume updating UI
    cht.Series.ResumeUpdates()

    'force redraw of chart
    cht.Update()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to loop, but you want to suspend updating the UI until you've done it for all points.  Try something like:

```
chart1.Series.SuspendUpdates();

foreach (Series s in chart1.Series)
{
    s.IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
}

chart1.Series.ResumeUpdates();
```

Comment: Well that's what I was afraid of, but let me give that a shot.